# Modifying string contents based on initial characters

Tags: python, css

I am trying to write a Python script that identifies the first two characters in a string and based on them makes specific changes to each string.

At work we have accounts on different systems. The account numbers change depending on which system you lookup the account. 
For example:
System 1 account number would be 23456
The same account in System 2 would be 24456

The initial 23 changes to 24 and the remainder stays the same. We have three different ways in which the first two characters can change.

I took a stab at writing a Python script that would identify the first two characters in each string and based on them make the appropriate change.

This is what I have so far:

```
import csv
inputfile = csv.reader(open('/users/user/accounts.csv', 'r'))
outputfile = open('/users/user/converted_accounts.txt', 'w')

for row in inputfile:
    if row.startswith('23')
       row.replace('23', '24', 1)
       print row
       outputfile.write(row)
    elif row.startswith('26')
         row.replace('26', '27', 1)
         print row
         outputfile.write(row)
    elif row.startswith('3')
         row.replace('3', '0', 1)
         print row
         outputfile.write(row)
    else:
         print(row)
         outputfile.write(row)
```

I am getting a syntax error beginning with my first if statement. I don't have any experience with Python and have been researching on my own the past few days trying to make it work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `:` at the end of the `if` and `elif` statements.
You'll also have issues w/ your `print` statements depending on whether you're using Python 2 or Python 3.

In Python 3 (since you're new to Python), your code should look like this:

```py
import csv
inputfile = csv.reader(open('/users/user/accounts.csv', 'r'))
outputfile = open('/users/user/converted_accounts.txt', 'w')

for row in inputfile:
    if row.startswith('23'):
       row.replace('23', '24', 1)
       print(row)
       outputfile.write(row)
    elif row.startswith('26'):
         row.replace('26', '27', 1)
         print(row)
         outputfile.write(row)
    elif row.startswith('3'):
         row.replace('3', '0', 1)
         print(row)
         outputfile.write(row)
    else:
         print(row)
         outputfile.write(row)
```

Also, look into using [context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) when opening files

Answer (score 0):

Further to dhui's reply with the idea to make your code work, below are some suggestions on cleaner ways to open/close your files for reading and writing (in a single statement), and simpler ways to make the string replacement.  Hope it helps.

```
inputfile = '/users/user/accounts.csv'
outputfile = '/users/user/converted_accounts.txt'

with open(inputfile, 'r') as ifile, \
     open(outputfile, 'w') as ofile:

    # create a loop to read the lines
    while True:
        line = ifile.readline()

        #exit the loop if there are no more lines
        if not line:
            break

        if line[0:2] == '23':
            line = '24' + line[2:]

        #elif... (write other conditions here)

        print(line)
        ofile.write(line)

print('finished!')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will definitely try these.